# Render tiles in the sea

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, worldwind, mod-tile

I installed a mapserver on my own server with mapnik, apache and mod_tile.

I build an application with WorldWind and my map server. My problem is that there are blank tiles instead of blue tiles to represent the sea.

Is there a simple way to remplace these tiles? Or do I have to change files like *generate_tiles.py* for example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your stylefile looks like, but for Openstreetmap tiles rendered with Mapnik, the background is blue by default

```
Map bgcolor="#b5d0d0"
```

and the coastline polygons introduce the white background for land areas.

---

**EDIT**

For missing tiles (with no data to be rendered), Openlayers uses:

```
OpenLayers.Util.OSM.MISSING_TILE_URL = "http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/img/404.png";

/**
 * Property: originalOnImageLoadError
 * {Function} Original onImageLoadError function.
 */
OpenLayers.Util.OSM.originalOnImageLoadError = OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError;

/**
 * Function: onImageLoadError
 */
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function() {
    if (this.src.match(/^http:\/\/[abc]\.[a-z]+\.openstreetmap\.org\//)) {
        this.src = OpenLayers.Util.OSM.MISSING_TILE_URL;
```

You can pre-render that "missing" tile in ocean blue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The problem is not the color of the style (I'm using OSM-Bright).
In the sea (or in areas with only one color), mapnik doesn't generate a tile at all. There's a blank space instead of the tile.

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to change code only in the server's side?

Comment: I am using the standard Postgis-mapnik toolchain, and for me the empty tiles (of size 103 bytes) get rendered. generate_tiles.py outputs an "Empty Tile" message for those. Maybe mod_tile surpresses the rendering?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. The problem was with WorldWind and not with my map server!